Merging data issue
I'm trying to merge data that contains results from LDA with a dataframe with the original documents. Both have a 'Code' column that matches.
However, the merge function fails, and I am left with the original document, sans new columns. I have gone and achieved it in R, but this program is supposed to complete the merge itself.
Below is my code snippet:
    # set up writing to a file
    # List to hold the processed data for each document
    documents_data = []

    # Loop over all documents in the data, and assign topic and probabilities to each
    for i in range(len(data)):
        # Get topic probabilities for the document
        topics = lm.get_document_topics(corpus[i])
        # Reorder topics according to pyLDAvis numbering and convert topic probabilities to float
        topics = [["Corpus_Topic " + str(to.index(topic[0] + 1)), float(topic[1])] for topic in topics]
        topics = sorted(topics, key=lambda x: x[0])
        topics_dict = dict(topics)

        # Get dominant topic and its value for the documents
        topics_dict['Corpus_dominant_topic'] = max(topics_dict, key=topics_dict.get)
        topics_dict['Corpus_dominant_value'] = float(topics_dict[topics_dict['Corpus_dominant_topic']])
        topics_dict["Code"] = codes[i]

        # Add the document's data to the list
        documents_data.append(topics_dict)
    # Convert documents_data to a dictionary with 'Code' as the key
    documents_dict = {doc['Code']: doc for doc in documents_data}    

    # Write the data to a JSON file
    with open('DataTextTopics.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(documents_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    # Ask the user to specify the master collection name
    master_collection_name = input("Please specify the collection name that you would like to merge the LDA results with. Note: collection must have a matching 'Code' column: ")
    collection = db[master_collection_name]

    # Load the documents from the collection into a Python list
    Social_data = list(collection.find())
    
    # Merge function.      
    def merge_Social_data(Social_data, documents_dict):
        for entry in Social_data:
        # Merge with form A topics
            code_a = entry.get('Code', '')
            if code_a in documents_dict:
                entry.update(documents_dict[code_a])
    
    # Social_data is already loaded from MongoDB
    merge_Social_data(Social_data, documents_data)
    
    # Function to convert ObjectId to str and remove if required
    def convert_id(entry):
        if isinstance(entry, dict):
            for key, value in list(entry.items()):
                if isinstance(value, ObjectId):
                    # Convert _id to str
                    entry[key] = str(value)
                elif isinstance(value, dict) or isinstance(value, list):
                    # Recursively call convert_id to handle nested dictionaries and lists
                    convert_id(value)
        elif isinstance(entry, list):
            for item in entry:
                # Recursively call convert_id to handle nested dictionaries and lists
                convert_id(item)

    # Assuming Social_data is your data loaded from MongoDB
    convert_id(Social_data) 
    
    # Save the merged data to a JSON file
    with open('Merged_Social_Data.json', 'w') as file:
         json.dump(Social_data, file, indent=4)

    # Ask the user to specify the new collection name
    new_collection_name = input("Please specify the new collection name to save the results: ")

    # Create a new collection (if it doesn't exist)
    new_collection = db[new_collection_name]

    # Insert the merged data
    new_collection.insert_many(Social_data)```


The full program is available here for context:
https://github.com/AlexHiscock56/Curating-Online-Heritage-The-case-of-the-Antonine-Wall-and-Roman-Scotland/blob/Analysis/User_Specified_LDA.py
